# vb.net messagebox yes.no buttons to have other text?

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

The following code is a nice example of generating a message box with two buttons.

```
Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to klick yes?", "Example", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

Though this is now dictating the question possed to either result in a yes or no answer. What if I want a create and Add buttons instead of Yes and no buttons example being...

```
Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to create a new customer or add an existing customer?", "New order", MessageBoxButtons.CreateAdd)
```

How could I achieve sothing like this?

Comment: Though you can create your own Dialog, this is by design because Yes/No questions are simplest and less error prone.  A magic MxgBox would soon morph into `result = MessageBox.Show("That account exists.  What is your desire?", btns.Edit, btns.EditMaster, btns.Cancel, btns.Return, btns.ViewOrders, bts.Delete, btns.GoBack")`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot achieve that with a `MessageBox`. If you want to customize the look and feel of those boxes you should write your own custom WinForm that you should display instad of using a MessageBox.

Answer (score 1):

Never you cannot do it with a message box, you can create customized winForms to achieve this target. and call it like `Form1.ShowDialog()` to get it like a message dialog box

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom form, with the custom buttons, and use `ShowDialog()`